# Vinaya Loopholes?

Tags: vinaya, mara

Did the Buddha ever say anything about monastics finding "loopholes" in the rules? A loophole would be something like: Showering when bathing is not allowed or living in a building  when the opposite sex lives in the building also but as long as the monastic is outside the building for a certain period of time every day the monastic can not be said to be living there. Also what are some of these possible loopholes?

Answer (score 7):

The Buddha laid down the four great standards to try and avoid this sort of thing:

> 1. "Bhikkhus, whatever I have not objected to, saying, 'This is not allowable,' if it fits in with what is not allowable, if it goes against what is allowable, that is not allowable for you.
> 2. "Whatever I have not objected to, saying, 'This is not allowable,' if it fits in with what is allowable, if it goes against what is not allowable, that is allowable for you.
> 3. "And whatever I have not permitted, saying, 'This is allowable,' if it fits in with what is not allowable, if it goes against what is allowable, that is not allowable for you.
> 4. "And whatever I have not permitted, saying, 'This is allowable,' if it fits in with what is allowable, if it goes against what is not allowable, that is allowable for you."
>
> (from Vinaya, Mv.VI. 40)
>
> Source: http://www.dhammawiki.com/index.php?title=4_great_standards

Still, where there's a will, there's a way, and it's easy to find loopholes if you're looking for them.